# Is django cache per database?

Tags: django, caching

When I use `django.core.cache`, is that a per-database cache?

For example, I have a database config that looks something like this:

```
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
    "NAME": "x",
    "USER": "x",
    "PASSWORD": "x",
    "HOST": "1.1.1.1",
    "PORT": "5432",
},
"rr": {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
    "NAME": "x",
    "USER": "x",
    "PASSWORD": "x",
    "HOST": "1.1.1.2",
    "PORT": "5432",
},
```

If I read an object from `default`, will the django cache save that for `rr` also?

Comment: If you read an object from `default`, the cache will do absolutely nothing. _Your code_ can cache the object with `cache.set()`, and whether you try to read the same cache key when you need an object from `rr` is again entirely up to you.

Comment: That answers my question--I'm new to django, thanks